# literal string with div tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have three strings and i want to concatenate them together, but one of them is within strong tag. The result is as below which is not as expected. What is the problem here?

**Result:**

> There is no Colors for `<strong>blah</strong>` in the database.

**Expected:**

> There is no Colors for **blah** in the database.

```
 const fruitResult = 'There is no Colors for ';
 const searchItem = `<strong>${fruitSearch}</strong>`;
 const fruitResult1 = ' in the database.';
const fruitResult2 = 'No Data available.';

   <div>
      <h2>
        {fruitSearch === '' 
        ? `${fruitResult2}`
        : `${fruitResult} ${searchItem} ${fruitResult1}`
        }
      </h2>
    </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-brook-q1rj93?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is a problem with how the string is being output to the DOM, not how it's being concatenated. Can you please show that code instead.

Comment: Also, you're defining `fruitResult`, not `fruitSearch`

Comment: Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to emit unescaped markup you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but as it says on the tin you should only do this if you control and trust the source.

```
const html = `${fruitResult} ${searchItem} ${fruitResult1}`;

<div>
  <h2 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
</div>
```

Here's a [working fork of your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-ully-ed3k42?file=/src/App.js) demo.

Comment: What if i have if condition in the h2?to show html or to show other text

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you need to conditionally choose whether to do html or text use an if statement or ternary expression.

Comment: I updated my question,check it now

Comment: What's the problem? Doing it conditionally doesn't really change anything. `const html = condition ? "thing one" : "thing two"`.